# How to add FTP users to my CentOS VPS

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

I am running a CentOS VPS.

Now I have installed an FTP server on the Server like this:

```
yum install vsftpd
```

And I have restarted the service as well.

However, when I point my browser to:

```
ftp://myStaticIP
```

it does not return anything.

Also, **how do I add an FTP user to my VPS** so that I can log in via a client?

Comment: It's more likely to be a firewall on your server blocking connections.  If it was an issue with users, you'd be offered a login prompt.  Check your firewall (and check you've configured vsftpd to listen on an external interface, not just localhost).

Comment: thank you. How to I check my firewall as well as how do I configure VSFTP to listen to an external interface? Will I use port 22 to connect to VSFTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally on StackExchange sites, answers are supposed to be comprehensive and not merely link to other resources.  However, you're asking two pretty basic, but very broad, questions here.

1. How do I configure the CentOS firewall?
2. How do I configure vsftpd on CentOS?

I can't write an answer which gives you everything you need to know about those, but I strongly suggest you find some good documentation and have a thorough read.  I don't use CentOS, so I have no direct experience of how it does things by default.

You may find these sources useful,

- [CentOS Firewall HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables)
- [RedHat Guide to configuring FTP Services (on CentOS Site)](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ftp-servers.html)
- [CentOS HowTo for chrooted vsftpd](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Chroot_Vsftpd_with_non-system_users)

I strongly encourage you to read the CentOS site, and read about the vsftpd service, and understand how to configure it, because even if someone on this site fixes your current issue, you'll run into another one and be back to ask about that.  You're not asking about a fault or an issue, you're asking for basic information on how to complete the setup, and the best way to achieve that is to read the documentation.

By all means, if you follow the documentation and something doesn't work, come back and formulate a question about that specific issue, but I urge you to not simply install services and hope they work without understanding how to configure them.

Comment: OK thank you EightBitTony. I have read a couple of tutorials and blogs about how to set it up, but not ONE of them tells you how you actually connect to it - How to setup a user, How to setup a password? I am using normal ftp on windows and I have a username and password that connect over ftp port 21...None of these tut tell you how you actually set up and ftp user, they only tell you how to configure the server.

Comment: Most FTP daemons on UNIX just the regular OS users.  Create new users with your favourite Linux user admin tool.

Comment: SO if I create a new user, it will automatically be able to log in via ftp? If not, where do I give the user permissions to do so?

Comment: This is the first google hit for 'vsftpd users' - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293